# Date getSeconds returns 0 when subtracting to another Date getSeconds

Tags: javascript

```
function returntime() {
  var start = new Date().getSeconds();
  var end = new Date().getSeconds();
  var totaltime = end - start;
  document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = totaltime;
}
```

> The totaltime return 0 but when i put start or end it shows the output.

Comment: Without some kind of delay, start and end are only a few micro/nanoseconds apart, so most likely will be in the same seconds amount

Comment: It is because the execution is so fast, there is no delay in seconds. If you replace `getSeconds` with `getTime`, you will be able to see the difference in miliseconds and you should get at least some result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delay between both statements.

```
var start = new Date().getSeconds();
  var end = new Date().getSeconds();
```

[image: See this image for debugger output]

Answer (score 0):

You ask for seconds. The code runs faster than a second.
For example, you get 9 seconds at the start and 9 seconds in the end.
If you ask for the milliseconds you will see that you will have a different result.